# GetProperty method is case sensitive for VB?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, case-sensitive

I was debugging one of the applications I work on and came across an interesting issue. For those unfamiliar with VB.NET, variable names are case insensitive. Therefore,

```
Dim foo As Integer
FOO = 5
System.Console.WriteLine(foO)
```

will compile and output a value of 5.

Anyways, the code I was working on was attempting to get a value from a property via reflection like so:

```
Dim value As Object = theObject.GetType().GetProperty("foo", BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(theObject, Nothing)
```

The code threw a NullReferenceException on this line. After doing some debugging, I noticed it is the GetProperty method that is returning Nothing, so GetValue is bombing. Looking at the class for theObject, it has a public property with the name **"Foo"**, not **"foo"** (notice the difference in casing). Apparently, since I was searching for lowercase foo, it could not find the property at all via reflection.

Thinking this was some weird fluke, I created a quick and dirty sandbox app to test this finding:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim test As New TestClass
        Dim propNames As New List(Of String)(New String() {"testprop", "testProp", "Testprop", "TestProp"})

        'Sanity Check
        System.Console.WriteLine(test.testprop)
        System.Console.WriteLine(test.testProp)
        System.Console.WriteLine(test.Testprop)
        System.Console.WriteLine(test.TestProp)

        For Each propName As String In propNames
            Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo = test.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            If propInfo Is Nothing Then
                System.Console.WriteLine("Uh oh! We don't have PropertyInfo for {0}", propName)
            Else
                System.Console.WriteLine("Alright, we have PropertyInfo for {0} and its value is: {1}", propName, propInfo.GetValue(test, Nothing))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Class TestClass
        Private _testProp As String = "I got it!"
        Public Property TestProp() As String
            Get
                Return _testProp
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _testProp = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Module
```

Much to my surprise, the output was as follows:

> ```
> I got it!
> I got it!
> I got it!
> I got it!
> Uh oh! We don't have PropertyInfo for testprop
> Uh oh! We don't have PropertyInfo for testProp
> Uh oh! We don't have PropertyInfo for Testprop
> Alright, we have PropertyInfo for TestProp and its value is: I got it!
> ```

TL;DR

Variable names in VB.NET are typically case insensitive. The GetProperty method on Type seems to be case sensitive when it comes to the property name. Is there a way to call this method "VB.NET style" and ignore case? Or am I SOL here and need to apply a C# mentality and worry about casing?

Comment: You need to apply a C# mentality and worry about casing.

Comment: `GetProperty()` is **.Net**, not VB.  That's your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm very well aware this is .NET versus VB. I actually started as a C# guy and was put on this project which is primarily VB. I wouldn't have thought twice about this scenario in C# but found it a bit baffling in VB is all.

Comment: My point is that .Net classes don't behave differently when called from VB or C#.

Comment: Right, that's understandable. It might not be intuitive though for someone who has only coded with VB (I work with plenty of people in this boat). Just as it might be counter-intuitive for GetProperty to actually be case insensitive for someone coming from a C# mindset. It is all .NET and CLR at the end of the day, but I typically code while thinking in a language, not a framework :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Variable names in VB.NET are typically case insensitive.

That's a trick done by the compiler. The CLR itself is case-sensitive. Since reflection has nothing to do with the compiler, case-sensitivity applies.

> Is there a way to call this method "VB.NET style" and ignore case?

Yes. Specify in your [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to IgnoreCase:

```
Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo = test.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed the BindingFlag.IgnoreCase enum. Thanks for the quick response!